# Inner Join returned values

Tags: mysql, sql, presto, trino

I have a query such as,

```
select name 

from employee 

inner join task on employee.id = task.employee_id 

order by name asc
```

Tables look like:

**employee**

```
id name 

1 Emily 

2 Sam 

3 AI 

4 Joe 

5 Daniel 

6 John
```

**task**

```
task_id employee_id

 A123       1 

 D456       3 

 A122       1
```

I believed the original query above would result in:

```
Al
Emily
```

But it is actually:

```
Al
Emily
Emily
```

I thought it would just return Emily once since inner join returns both values in both tables, but doesnt Emily appear only once in the employee table? I dont understand why it returns Emily twice even though it is listed twice in the task table?

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: No I dont want to change it i Just wanted to understand why with the given query it returns emily 2 times in the inner join

Comment: ...because Emily has 2 tasks.

Comment: Use `select name, task_id ...` and you'll see why.

Comment: but isnt it with inner join it only returns values that exist in both tables? Emily exists in both but it returns as many rows as she exists in?

Comment: A join is essentially a Cartesian product (a x b). Yours is a subset of that (a x b where both a and b are Emily) - this is an oversimplification, but correct enough for your example.

Comment: `Emily exists in both but it returns as many rows as she exists in?` yes, this is exactly what happen.  think about this way, `join` find Emily have two relation in `task`, it won't randomly decide which one you want so it will just give you both rows.

Comment: @Strawberry so every join ( inner, left, outer) is a Cartesian product? meaning it is (a x b) or will return all records that exist in either table if that one row exists in both right

Comment: in this case alter your `select` so it also include `task_id` and `employee_id` from `task` table and I think it will be slightly easier to understand the logic.

Comment: More accurately, only 'cross join' provides a genuine Cartesian product. But yes, inner join will return a value from 'b' for every corresponding value from 'a' (and vice versa, because b x a = a x b). LEFT JOIN returns a value from 'b' for every value from 'a' regardless of correspondence (but not vice versa), and the situation gets more complicated still when we factor in nulls, but that feels like a digression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emily has two tasks, hence her name record gets duplicated in the join, once for each match.  I might use exists logic to get the result you want here:

```sql
SELECT e.name
FROM employee e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM task t WHERE t.employee_id = e.id);
```

Read in plain English, the above query says to return any employee name (once) for which we can find at least one task in the `task` table.

Comment: Thanks this helps, but I was just confused looking at that output from the inner join, so if you inner join I understand that it returns only records that exist in both tables. But what I didn't understand is that if in ONE of the tables the ID that is being joined on exists more than 1 time, it returns as many times as that exsits?

Comment: @Chris90 I think I get your doubts...yes, an employee record can be used more than once in the join.  So, Emily's employee record gets conceptually "recycled" as many times as there are matching records in the task table.  In this case, we end up with two Emily records.

Comment: Thanks I just didn't conceptually ever think of it and was confused when looking at that simple example above, if i am inner joining on an order id with two tables and one table contains a location of that order every 5 mins it will return every record of location from that second table correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.  But think about it: if joining worked as you previosly thought, then how could you control _which_ of the 2 Emily records gets returned?  You can't, and so such an operation might not be very useful.

Comment: so if in the original scenario, she had an extra record in the employee table it would return emily 3 times?

Comment: I'd recommend writing this as `e.id IN (SELECT t.employee_id FROM task t)`. BTW PrestoSQL (now called Trino) can efficiently include Semi-join together with other Joins in Cost-Based Join opimizations.